# Installing ubuntu 19.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, 19.04

I am currently running a dual boot system for windows 10 and ubuntu 18.10. I have 1.5 TB for windows and 500 GB for ubuntu. I want to do a **fresh** installation of ubuntu 19.04, and completely remove windows from my laptop, giving me 2TB for ubuntu. I know how do a fresh installation, but I don't know how should I do it so as to remove windows and merge those 2 partitions into 1. Can someone please give me some hints on how I can do this? Thanks...

On a side note, I read on Ubuntu's site that that 19.04 won't receives updates after Jan 2020, does it mean that it may be a bad idea to install 19.04?

Comment: No Ubuntu 19.04 won't receive updates after that date, but after 19.10's been released you'll be offered the chance to release-upgrade to 19.10 (or you can do it yourself any time after 19.10's release date [plus a few days]). I would boot a live system (19.04's install media), and using `gparted` delete your windows partition, then 'grow' your 18.10 partition to use the whole disk as you'd like, then do your install from that media. Of course backup any data I felt was valuable before any of this.

Comment: @user68186 with this method, will my whole 2 TB be available for use in ubuntu? (The main issue is that I'll have a dataset spanning aroung 1 TB, so it is important that have large space available for ubuntu)

Comment: If you want a fresh installation; erase everything & install is far quicker. If you have some user data you want to keep, I'd expand as I stated before, use 'something-else' and ensure 'format' checkbox is not checked. This takes note of additional apps you've installed in your 18.10, erases system directories, installs, then re-adds apps you added (if in repositories). It doesn't touch your user data (unless you accidentally selected format).  Erasing & re-creating partitions is faster than growing them.

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot for the help. I'll keep these points in mind :)

Comment: @user68186 yes you (both of you) have :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Ubuntu partition the disk when we choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984042/how-does-ubuntu-partition-the-disk-when-we-choose-erase-disk-and-install-ubuntu) and [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/16366/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Erase and Install (by @user68186)**

When you start the fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04, you should see an option to erase everything and install. This will remove all the partitions and create new ones spanning the whole 2TB.

[image: Image provided by user68186]

This option will delete everything in that disk! That means Windows, Ubuntu 18.10, any data partition, any recovery partition etc. etc.

**Alternative option**

Alternatively you could boot a live system (eg. Ubuntu 19.04's install media), and using `gparted` to delete your windows partition, then 'grow' your 18.10 partition to use the whole disk as you'd like, then do your install from that media.

You can opt to install using 'something-else' and ensure 'format' checkbox is **not** checked. This takes note of additional apps you've installed in your 18.10, erases system directories, installs, then re-adds apps you added (if in repositories). It doesn't touch your user data (unless you accidentally selected format).

Of course don't forget to backup any data you don't want to lose, and please note this will be slower than erase/install!

**19.04's coming EOL**

Ubuntu 19.04 won't receive updates after that EOL in late Jan-2020, but a few days after Ubuntu 19.10's release, you'll be offered the chance to release-upgrade to 19.10 (or you can do it yourself any time after this until shortly after 19.04's EOL).

*This is a consolidation of comments by @user68186 and myself*