# Simplest way to completely remove Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I need to uninstall 14.04 and install a more recent version of Ubuntu, let say 18.04...

Comment: You don't uninstall the prior OS, you just install over it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Ubuntu partition the disk when we choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984042/how-does-ubuntu-partition-the-disk-when-we-choose-erase-disk-and-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are only using a single root partition and don't need any of your data, you can simply download and boot the installer and re-format your existing root partition.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is still important I would recommend remove the old drive from your computer and install the new system on a new SSD. Then connect the old drive to your newly installed computer and copy all important files to the new SSD.