# How to replace Windows with Ubuntu while I have both in the bios but deleted previous Ubuntu partition?

Tags: xubuntu

1. I have a HP ENVY 13 ah-0xxxnx and it had Windows10. Then I created an Ubuntu partition long ago-dual boot.
2. Then recently I deleted Ubuntu partition but still in the OS Boot manager there is Ubuntu and Windows boot manager.
3. I reinstalled Windows10 using bootable usb but it always runs into error WHEA_UNCORRECTAE ERROR.
   I think it has to do with a driver, IDE ATA/ATAPI Controllers: Standard SATA AHCI Controller. Because all other drivers got updated but this says not working properly.
4. Because of the issue above, now I want to remove Windows10 entirely and install Ubuntu only. How do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Ubuntu partition the disk when we choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984042/how-does-ubuntu-partition-the-disk-when-we-choose-erase-disk-and-install-ubuntu) *When installing in UEFI mode an EFI system partition will be created, in accordance with UEFI requirements; it will be mounted as `/boot/efi`.*

Comment: Depending on the BIOS, boot entries may remain. Go into the BIOS and remove them if possible. Make sure that USB is on top of the bootorder. Usually SATA is best to set at AHCI (not RAID or anything else, that may cause boot issues). Then just reinstall Ubuntu with a USB drive.