# How to remove Elementary OS and install Ubuntu Over it, without burning to a DVD or USB?

Tags: pantheon

I was previously an elementary os 5.1. I want to know how to do it so I can use Ubuntu. Ideally not by installing ubuntu via burning dvd and usb.

(Original title translates to: Removing the base os to make it ubuntu)

--  translated online from

Original Title: Menghapus os dasar agar menjadi ubuntu

Saya sebelum nya pengguna elementary os 5.1.
Saya ingin mengetahui bagaimana cara nya agar saya bisa menggunakan ubuntu tetapi dengan tidak menginstall ubuntu melalui pembakaran dvd dan usb.

Comment: You can download the ISO and have it stored on a partition, then modify `grub` so it lists that option, and install from that (I've done it where I don't have working USB ports).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Ubuntu partition the disk when we choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984042/how-does-ubuntu-partition-the-disk-when-we-choose-erase-disk-and-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

I have a laptop with dead USB ports (*old thinkpad t42p*) that I use in QA-testing Ubuntu *flavors*.

I download the *daily* ISOs onto the local HDD to a location I selected.

The following entries were then added to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` (*this is a snippet only as it lists many other ISO options*)

```
menuentry "Lubuntu QA testing 18.04.4 ISO noPAE" {
    set root=(hd0,7)
    set isofile="/lubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-i386.iso"
        loopback loop (hd0,7)/lubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-i386.iso
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/lubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-i386.iso forcepae --forcepae --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
menuentry "Lubuntu QA testing 18.04.5 ISO noPAE" {
    set root=(hd0,7)
    set isofile="/lubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso"
        loopback loop (hd0,7)/lubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/lubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso forcepae --focepae  --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
menuentry "Xubuntu QA testing 18.04.5 ISO noPAE" {
    set root=(hd0,7)
    set isofile="/xubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso"
        loopback loop (hd0,7)/xubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/xubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso forcepae --focepae  --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

Note:  The 'forcepae --forcepae' is required only because this really old pentium M device requires those kernel lines to boot. It's actually handy, as on other (*prehistoric pentium*) devices I have to manually type that detail onto the kernel line for the laptops with working thumb-drives on each QA-test boot.

You'll have to change the ISO files to match your system, plus location of where you stored the ISO files. Mine were in / of sda7.  This is intended as example only.

To re-create the grub file use the command `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Oke, terima kasih. Akan saya coba cara yang anda berikan pada saya. Semoga ini berhasil.

Comment: Also if you're going to format or overwrite the partition on which the ISO is read from, you'll want to use a `toram` option, ie. refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootToRAM  (there's a better page, can't currently find it sorry)

Comment: Untuk memulai install apakah saya harus mengklik kiri 2x di file iso atau tetap harus melalui bios?

Comment: I assume you're using `grub` to select what you're trying to boot; the `update-grub` command I mention at the end will update the grub menu using the 40_custom and other files. On booting the grub menu appears, I arrow down to it and press ENTER.  I don't know Elementary sorry; but what I mentioned will work with Debian or Ubuntu installed `grub`  (also tested with OpenSuSE & I believe it'll work with Fedora and others too but I've not used it beyond Debian/Ubuntu/OpenSuSE though the `update-grub` command of course differs with OpenSuSE/Fedora/..).

Comment: @guiverc Should be `sudo update-grub`.