# How to remove Ubuntu and install Windows with no USB or CD?

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows, windows-10, removing

My situation is slightly different from that described in other similar threads. Specifically:

- I have Ubuntu installed and it's the only OS installed.
- I have a Windows 10 ISO but no USB or CD.
- I want to install Windows while at the same time completely removing Ubuntu.

Comment: How to install Windows does not seem to be an Ubuntu-related question. However you manage to install Windows, if you do it correctly it will automatically remove Ubuntu.

Comment: How is this in any way Ubuntu related?

Comment: The same way I boot up Lubuntu (& other *flavors*) on a machine with dead-USB ports (& no working cd/dvd tray), make the bootloader provide a list of what my options are (which include .ISO files located on the HDD that works). They are put there via network cable or wifi.  I don't see your question being on-topic too as you're asking about windows though https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  (*but I've said what I'd do, it'll boot windows XP ISOs but I've not tried anything later*)

Comment: It's an Ubuntu question in that my current OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: I haven't tried... Make Tech Easier: [How to Create a Windows 10 Installer USB from Linux](https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-windows-installer-usb-linux/)

Comment: Maybe useful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272343/how-to-remove-elementary-os-and-install-ubuntu-over-it-without-burning-to-a-dvd/1272354#1272354

Comment: The OP is asking a very good question about how to use Ubuntu to install another OS. Might as well close all the previous questions on Ask Ubuntu about the use of YUMI, MultibootUSB and Ventoy. or bootin ISO files.

Comment: @Edgar Derby: This recent question should provide you with a solution of how to install Windows 10 from Ubuntu without the need for DVD or USB: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284364/installing-windows-10-without-usb-with-ubuntu-18-04-this-is-not-a-bootable-disk My comment attempts to clear up the cloudy points.

Answer (score 0):

No usb? Why? You will be super easy to go if you have a minimum 8gb usb.
But in case you are really obsessed to do so, you can try the steps below however I hadn't tried this yet so be careful and know what you are doing.

1. From ubuntu make a new partition of around 7gb (you can resize from end of root partition too so no live medium is necessary).
2. Now manage another partition of around 32gb or many as you can
3. Create a bootable disk on the partition you created in step 1 by following https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-windows-installer-usb-linux/ or anything smilar tutorial
4. If you are in luck, in the boot menu of your bios (not grub) you will see the option to start windows disk image with similar label (remember to disable secure boot and also set proper boot priority)
   Else not shown you should really bring a usb/cd from anywhere
5. If windows installation wizard starts you can install install format and install windows in the partition created at step 2
6. On successful installation of windows you can then again layout the partition the way you want.

**Note Again: I had not experimented this on single drive, so be careful**