# I have Dell Inspiron with Windows10 installed. I would like to switch to Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, dell, inspiron

I need to install an Ubuntu distribution (preferably Kubuntu), overwriting the existing OS (Windows10). Do I have to make changes to the BIOS to make this work?

Comment: Maybe. However "Dell Inspiron" says nothing useful. There are hundreds of different models and configurations spanning more than 15 years. Much less and obviously more recent are those with preinstalled Windows 10 but even so we're talking of dozens, some of which the only thing they have in common is the vendor's attributed model "badge".

Comment: Best to have full backup of Windows, beside any data you want to save. We often find users who try to jump into the deep end of the pool & have issues. Some games or programs just do not work in Linux and then user wants Windows back again. Dell typically needs UEFI update, if SSD also SSD firmware update.
It needs UEFI setting for drives changed to AHCI, not Intel RST nor RAID. But if dual booting with Windows you must first install AHCI drivers into Windows or it will not boot.
Often better to have UEFI Secure boot off. And UEFI fast boot off as you are making changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Ubuntu partition the disk when we choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984042/how-does-ubuntu-partition-the-disk-when-we-choose-erase-disk-and-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Your question depends heavily on what hardware you have, so it would be helpful for you to read the documentation for your motherboard.

Before installing an operating system is the best time to update your motherboard firmware, but it's probably not required. If you chose to do so, follow the documentation for your motherboard carefully and do not interrupt a firmware flash in progress.

Ubuntu maintains official [tutorials](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials) for basic tasks such as:

- [Create a bootable USB stick on Windows](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- [Install Ubuntu desktop](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop)

You will have to consult with your motherboard's documentation for the method to boot from Ubuntu installation media.

The tutorial for creating bootable media on Windows suggests Rufus to flash the Ubuntu ISO to the USB, but I find [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to be a lot more user-friendly for this task.

If this is the first time you are installing Ubuntu and you choose to completely replace Windows, you can ensure that the installation will go smoothly by formatting (erasing) your disk prior to the installation. To do this, boot from the USB and choose "Try Ubuntu" and use the "Disks" application to "Format" your disk. This will effectively erase the disk. That makes sure that the Ubuntu installer is working with a clean disk and it will offer you a guided installation and create the needed partitions and file systems automatically.

It's generally recommended to choose the GPT partition scheme when formatting the disk to install a modern operating system.  With a GPT disk, when it's time to install Ubuntu, make sure you boot the USB in "UEFI" mode instead of BIOS/legacy.  Again, you will need to check the documentation for your motherboard to learn the particular quirks of your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

My experience installing Linux (usually Linux Mint) in modern laptops (the ones with UEFI BIOS) has been annoying when trying to install both operating systems partitioning by myself. But when overwriting the whole hdd to install a fresh Linux (letting the installer do the complete job) usually has ended in a success.
Bear in mind that maybe you have to look for the MBR (Master Boot Record) writing protection that sometimes are turned on to avoid viruses and other malware write it.
Anyway, good luck in your trial and welcome to freedom!