# Format HDD and install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, format

my name is Tonny.
I have Ubuntu 20.04 but I also have windows on the same machine.
My question is: how can I format my HDD delete everything and install again only  Ubuntu?

Comment: Boot the Ubuntu installation/live media, select "erase and install..." Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Ubuntu partition the disk when we choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984042/how-does-ubuntu-partition-the-disk-when-we-choose-erase-disk-and-install-ubuntu)

Comment: If you are asking, you sound like a new user. Most new users may like Ubuntu, but it has a learning curve. And then find one application or game that only runs in Windows and want to reinstall Windows. So best to backup Windows before erasing it. Some users, have just removed Windows drive & put on shelf and installed Ubuntu to new drive. Then later if selling system, can restore Windows drive as often cannot sell as Ubuntu system.